# How to set uiculture for AjaxControl

Tags: asp.net, ajax, uiculture

I have an asp.net application that is entirely in the Dutch language (Culture and UICulture) This is set in the header of the aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" UICulture="nl" Culture="nl-NL" CodeBehind="CSSSR_BlokjesSchema.aspx.vb" EnableEventValidation="false" Inherits="CS_SSR_RAIO.CSSSR_BlokjesSchema" %>
```

This workes perfectly, but not for the Ajax calendar extender. In that component, the dates and month names are still displayed in English.

[image]

What am i forgetting?? What setting in Ajax makes my calendar use the Culture i set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself

The toolkit scriptmanager needs to be explicitly told that is has to use localisation:

```
<ajaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" runat="server" CombineScripts="true"></ajaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

After i changed this, the calendar was showing the date descriptions in Dutch

[image]